# Create Facebook Auto Post

Tags: facebook, post

I want to make a site, that uses Facebook Auto post.

When a user clicks on a video or article, he will be redirected to the Facebook App Login page. Then when he is connected with Facebook, the site will post on the user's wall.

I followed this instructions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/

My code look like this:

```
$app_id = "xxxxx";
$app_secret = "xxxx";
$my_url = "http://xxxx.com/";

session_start();

$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

if(empty($code)) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); // CSRF protection
    $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
        . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
        . $_SESSION['state'] . "&scope=publish_actions";

   echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
}
```

How can I embed the Auto post code?

Comment: Please also keep in mind to provide the user clear indications about these posts or your application might be reported as SPAM

Answer (score 0):

This should just work fine:

```
$attachment = array(
   'message' => "Your post message goes here",
   'access_token' => $accessToken // the obtained access token with publish_stream permission
);

$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/', 'post', $attachment);

var_dump($result); // echo the post_id
```